# Preventing header from being fixed until the menu has been opened once

Tags: mmenu

I'm using **mmenu.js** (v9.3) with a single-page site - it all works, with the *pageScroll* add-on allowing same-page links. BUT my fixed header is not fixed until you click the menu hamburger and close it again. And in desktop view the hamburger is `display: none` so no way to make the header fix, even if I could live with that.

In older versions of mmenu.js there was a fixed header add-on, but this is no longer an option, presumably integrated into the main code.

Not loading mmenu.js returns my header to fixed so I know it's the culprit, and I have no errors in console.

Anyone come across this and found a fix? Better still is the author out there? - I paid for a multisite license.